# Django Check for duplicates with 2 model fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, sorting, django-models

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class UssdCode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How can I get the admin to alert me and reject my entry when I try to add a new object that has the same 'code' and 'product' as an object already in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make it unique together. Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) of the [*Django Constraint framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/) for that:

```
# since Django-2.2

class UssdCode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['code', 'product'], name='code_product')
        ]
```

Prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use the [**`unique_together`** meta option [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
# before Django-2.2 (still works on Django-3.0)

class UssdCode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['code', 'product']]
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Do you have any idea on how to implement this 'unique_together' if you are using the https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export package for importing models?

Comment: @ebere: normally this is also enforced at the database level, so the database will normally reject duplicates in the combinations of these fields.